# How to edit an order to add the shipping line item to prevent AJAX error

Tags: 7, commerce, ajax

Using Drupal 7.61 and Drupal Commerce 7.x-1.14 (+ Commerce Shipping 7.x-2.3 and Flat Rate 7.x-1.0-beta2)

My client has (probably) deleted the shipping line item for an order and he has tried to edit this order to add a new shipping line item (4 shipping services set by Flat rate).

We get the same AJAX error each time we try :

`DatabaseTransactionOutOfOrderException: in DatabaseConnection->rollback()(line 1094 of /home/my_website/public_html/includes/database/database.inc).`

Where should I look to fix this issue?

First there was also a Rules issue and I managed to fix it with a specific condition but we still can not edit the order to add a shipping line item.

EDIT : after a couple of new tries, it seems like the Rules Collect rate : flat rates fired and failed somewhere... some values are missing when adding a shipping line item through Order edit form, compared to Checkout where everything goes well

EDIT/ANSWER : Thanks to Clive's comments, I found a solution. Actually, multiple savepoints were involved in my process (one to save the new shipping line item in Drupal database and an another one to send it in an external database through a specific Rule). That makes sense when you read documentation on rollback(). So I have changed my Rule with a special condition related to shipping and now it works.

Comment: This doesn't look like an Ajax error...

Comment: Sorry but we can't debug this from here, that'll have to be done by someone with access to the site and database. As luck would have it this has been asked before hopefully the answers to the duplicate will get you on the right path